# Spring/Java web: how can I know a request is a form post?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I am doing a Spring website. The website has many pages visitors can get. It also allows visitors to fill and submit a few forms.

I would like to use a Spring interceptor (as a central place) to examine each web request from visitors. How can I decide whether a web request is a get request or a form post?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: It will be determined by the HttpServletRequest request parameter for the preHandle Method in the interceptor --- - HttpServletRequest has a "getMethod()" which will return the type of request

Comment: Would HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod() be a start? If you need to be sure about the form a hidden field might also come handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getMethod() as follows -

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Request Intercepted for : "
                + request.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println("Request type : "
                + request.getMethod());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Form [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29)

> java.lang.String getMethod()
>
> Returns the name of the HTTP method with which this request was made, for example, GET, POST, or PUT. Same as the value of the CGI variable REQUEST_METHOD.
>
> Returns:
>           a String specifying the name of the method with which this request was made